# How do I read blood pressure data for HealthKit in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, healthkit

I have problems trying to figure out how to read blood pressure data in HealthKit, especially since understanding how HKCorrelationQuery works for blood pressure for Objective C isn't well documented on the Developer website or tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following code to read blood pressure data through HealthKit. I found you can't read systolic or diastolic values directly. You need to make a HKCorrelationQuery for blood pressure data and then for each correlation, you need to do some digging in order to finally get a value for blood pressure. Hope this helps!

```
- (void)readBloodPressure {

HKQuantityType *systolicType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureSystolic];
HKQuantityType *diastolicType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureDiastolic];
HKCorrelationType *bloodPressureType =
[HKCorrelationType correlationTypeForIdentifier:HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierBloodPressure];

HKCorrelationQuery *query =
[[HKCorrelationQuery alloc]
 initWithType:bloodPressureType predicate:nil
 samplePredicates:nil
 completion:^(HKCorrelationQuery *query, NSArray *correlations, NSError *error) {
     if (correlations == nil) {
         // Provide proper error handling here...
         NSLog(@"An error occurred while searching for blood pressure data %@",
               error.localizedDescription);
         abort();
     }
     for (HKCorrelation *correlation in correlations) {
          HKQuantitySample *systolicSample = [[correlation objectsForType:systolicType] anyObject];
         HKQuantity *systolicQuantity = [systolicSample quantity];
         HKQuantitySample *diastolicSample = [[correlation objectsForType:diastolicType] anyObject];
         HKQuantity *diastolicQuantity = [diastolicSample quantity];
         double systolicd = [systolicQuantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit millimeterOfMercuryUnit]];
         double diastolicd = [diastolicQuantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit millimeterOfMercuryUnit]];
         NSLog(@"Systolic %f",systolicd);
         NSLog(@"Diastolic %f",diastolicd);
         NSLog(@"Date %@",systolicSample.startDate);

         [self saveBloodPressureIntoApp:systolicd withDiastolic:diastolicd withDate:systolicSample.startDate];


     }

 }];

[self.healthStore executeQuery:query];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You **can** read systolic and diastolic values directly from blood pressure from HealthKit entries:

```
NSSet *querySet = [NSSet setWithObjects:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureSystolic],
                    [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureDiastolic], nil];

for (HKQuantityType *quantityType in querySet) {
    HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:quantityType predicate:nil limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit sortDescriptors:nil resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (results && results.count > 0) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do something with results, which will be an array of HKQuantitySample objects
      });
}
```

Then, you just have to do some digging to get whatever info you want from those objects, as Oliver said.